# Избавиться от callback hell nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, promise

Всем привет. Есть небольшая проблема. Написал функцию для транзакций в mysql. Но она имеет очень большую вложенность. Опыта с таким пока немного, поэтому не очень получается избавиться от коллбеков.
Может кто-то подскажет, посоветует что-то?)
Вот сам класс с методом для транзакций.

```
class Connection {
    constructor(dbConfig) {
        this.connection = mysql.createPool(dbConfig);

        this.connection.getConnection((err) => {
            if (err) {
                if (err.code === 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST') {
                    console.error('Database connection was closed.');
                }
                if (err.code === 'ER_CON_COUNT_ERROR') {
                    console.error('Database has too many connections.');
                }
                if (err.code === 'ECONNREFUSED') {
                    console.error('Database connection was refused.');
                }
            }else {
                console.log("Successfully connected to the database.");
            }
        });
    }

    //Избавиться от callback hell
    transaction(queryArray){
        return new Promise((res, rej) =>{
            this.connection.getConnection((err, connection)=>{
                connection.beginTransaction(err =>{
                    if (err) rej(err);

                    connection.query(queryArray[0], (err, result) => {
                        if (err) return connection.rollback(()=> {throw err});

                        const booksId = result.insertId;

                        connection.query(queryArray[1], (err, result) =>{
                            if (err) return connection.rollback(()=> {throw err});

                            const authorId = result.insertId;

                            connection.query(queryArray[2](booksId, authorId), (err,result)=>{
                                if (err) return connection.rollback(()=> {throw err});
                                connection.commit( err => {
                                    if (err) return connection.rollback(()=> {throw err});
                                });
                                res(result);
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Первое, что приходит на ум- это уйти от анонимности в пользу именованных функций. Да, формально вложенность сохранится, но это не будет такая мега-простыня, которую нужно будет лицезреть зайдя в 1 функцию.

Comment: @iluxa1810 а с помощью промисов? `then ... catch`

Comment: `async/await` + `try..catch`, м? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await

Comment: Хелпер-методы конечно придется писать, но оно того стоит. Заодно логика класса структурируется (сейчас все как-то кучно, дело даже не в пирамиде ужаса, а в попытке засунуть несколько действий в один метод).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

как то так

```
transaction(queryArray) {
      return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        const resultArray = [];
        this.connection.getConnection(async (err, connection) => {
          await asyncTransaction(connection, async () => {
            const customers = await asyncQuery(connection, "select * from 
              'customers'")
            resultArray.push({
              customers,
            });
          });
          res(resultArray);
        });
     });
    }



    function asyncTransaction(transactionEvent) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.connection.beginTransaction(async (err) => {
          reject(err);
          await transactionEvent();
          resolve();
        });
      });
    }

    function asyncQuery(query, needCommit = false) {

      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.connection.query(query, (err, result) => {
          if (err) reject(err);
          if (needCommit) {
            connection.commit((err) => {
              if (err) reject(err);
            });
          }
          resolve(result);
        })
      });
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, чуть позже попробую)

Comment: не 100 процентов что просто скопировать и будет работать. там надо решить как быть с коннектом. либо прокидывать в методы либо выносить  в  глобальную переменную что бы была видна во всем классе.

Comment: Я понял. Мне сама идея понятна) Спасибо еще раз)

Comment: Так коннект же в конструкторе класса прописан, просто через this обращаюсь и все.
Или я вас не правильно понял, простите?))

Answer (score 1):

На основе вышеприведенного ответа внес правки и получил желаемый результат, теперь класс выглядит вот так:

```
class Connection {
    constructor(dbConfig) {
        this.connection = mysql.createPool(dbConfig);

        this.connection.getConnection((err) => {
            if (err) {
                if (err.code === 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST') {
                    console.error('Database connection was closed.');
                }
                if (err.code === 'ER_CON_COUNT_ERROR') {
                    console.error('Database has too many connections.');
                }
                if (err.code === 'ECONNREFUSED') {
                    console.error('Database connection was refused.');
                }
            }else {
                console.log("Successfully connected to the database.");
            }
        });
    }


    transaction(queryArray){
        return new Promise((res, rej) => {
            const resultArray = [];
            this.connection.getConnection(async (err, connection) => {
                await this.asyncTransaction(connection, async () => {
                    const books = await this.asyncQuery(connection, queryArray[0]);
                    const authors = await this.asyncQuery(connection, queryArray[1]);
                    const books_data = await this.asyncQuery(connection, queryArray[2](books.insertId, authors.insertId), true);
                    resultArray.push({books_data});
                });
                res(resultArray);
            });
        });
    }

    asyncTransaction(connection, transactionEvent) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            connection.beginTransaction(async (err) => {
                if(err) reject(err);
                await transactionEvent();
                resolve();
            });
        });
    }

    asyncQuery(connection, query, needCommit = false) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            connection.query(query, (err, result) => {
                if (err) return connection.rollback(()=> {throw err});
                if (needCommit) {
                    connection.commit((err) => {
                        if (err) return connection.rollback(()=> {throw err});
                    });
                }
                resolve(result);
            })
        });
    }
}
```